# allow users to register with the same email address in 3

Tags: joomla

I want to register users but they should be able to register with the same email address, they are going to login with a username that is generated for them, so email is not important. How and where can i dissable or work the code to not check the database "user table: for duplicate email addresses.

Comment: Email addresses are used to guarantee uniqueness. You don't care about this?

Comment: Why you would want to do this? What's the purpose and the benefit? Apart the uniqueness, there will be no easy to way to get in touch with the users, send credential reminders and such...

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Why this needs to be done, Is users may have many apartments, and eveytime a user wants to upload a apartment, they have to insert a new email address. The system was build like this, now we need to take this out. so 1 user can register with one email addres everytime, when a property is registered a new username and and password get send to the user " for that property".

Comment: oh man, I would suggest to revise this workflow and enable your registered users to create/manage as many properties they want under their one single account. That would make sense to me and to your users (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an override for the signup page with a hidden email field, and fill the field with a randomly generated email address.

Create a folder /templates/Your_Template/html/com_users/registration

Copy the file /components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php to it.

Replace the content of this file with the form you want to use. 
The form is generated dynamicly so you might try going to your site's existing sign up page in your browser and copying the html source to get the form's basic structure. Then you can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

It is important not to change the Joomla core code otherwise your changes will be lost or your page might crash after performing an update. **Implement this as Joomla plugin.**

By the time a user is created the check for an existing email address is performed in the Joomla user table code located in `libraries\joomla\table\user.php`

The code section for this check in **Joomla! 3.4.3 Stable** can be found between the the **lines 237 - 251**:

```
        // Check for existing email
        $query->clear()
            ->select($this->_db->quoteName('id'))
            ->from($this->_db->quoteName('#__users'))
            ->where($this->_db->quoteName('email') . ' = ' . $this->_db->quote($this->email))
            ->where($this->_db->quoteName('id') . ' != ' . (int) $this->id);
        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $xid = (int) $this->_db->loadResult();

        if ($xid && $xid != (int) $this->id)
        {
            $this->setError(JText::_('JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_EMAIL_INUSE'));

            return false;
        }
```

The next step is to create a plugin* and to copy the `user.php` file into the plugin directory. There you **comment the above mentioned section** of the code so it won't be executed. Furthermore you need an additional php and xml file (XML installation file) with the file name of your plugin (you can choose the name).
In the php file you refer to the adjusted `user.php` file:

```
<?php

    // no direct access
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;

    // Replace core JTableUser with override version
    include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/plugins/system/<name_of_your_plugin>/user.php';
```

In your XML installation file you put the information needed to describe your plugin and the files it contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.0" type="plugin" group="system">
    <name><![CDATA[name_of_the_plugin]]></name>
    <author><![CDATA[author]]></author>
    <creationDate>date</creationDate>
    <copyright><![CDATA[copyright]]></copyright>
    <authorEmail><![CDATA[email]]></authorEmail>
    <authorUrl><![CDATA[url]]></authorUrl>
    <version><![CDATA[version]]></version>
    <license><![CDATA[licencse]]></license>
    <description>PLG_SYSTEM_NAME_OF_YOUR_PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION</description>

    <files>
        <filename plugin="name_of_the_plugin">name_of_the_plugin.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>user.php</filename>
    </files>

    <languages folder="language">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_name_of_the_plugin.ini</language>
    </languages>

    <config>
    </config>

</extension>
```

Now can **install/activate** the plugin and users will be able to use the same email address.

*Information on how to create a plugin for Joomla can be found in the official Joomla documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla